# Say, how do I log out?

Tags: support, logout

I keep getting this thing where it says

[image]

no matter what I do. So I thought I'd log out. But I can't.

What should I do?

Comment: You say "there is no log out button", it's under the "StackExchange" drop down (or [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/logout)), or do you just mean you get that error when you try to log out via that button?

Comment: It took me quite a while to find the log out button too. Although this question is very simple, the fact that it was asked may be evidence that the log out button should be placed somewhere more discoverable.

Comment: As a side note, if that's an error you're getting while saving your profile, logging out isn't gonna help. I'm turning up 4 different accounts linked to your email address (the one you're posting from here + 3 others that just have unregistered profiles on other sites in the SE network), so I'm going to recommend you [contact us](/contact) to get this resolved.

Comment: hi @AdamLear thanks and if you see this message, thanks I have tried to contact the help desk, showing them this message!  amazed I have had FOUR accounts over the years  :O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logout button is located here:
[image: non-SO site switcher]

Or, in the new Stack Overflow/Meta Stack Overflow top bar, here:

[image: new SO top bar site switcher]

Comment: Hi 54D, thanks for that.  Man, that is obscure.